# Ethernet set up for VNC

Tags: networking, vnc

Is there a new procedure to install VNC on the Pi 2 Model B?

I've tried several and got one to work but after hours of work only to find that when I rebooted it asks for a password and go stuck in that loop.

Comment: There are multiple VNC Servers available (at least for Raspbian). Please provide more info, like the commands you used to set it up...

Answer (score 1):

There is alpha version of RealVNC optimized for the Raspberry Pi.

You can read more about it at: https://github.com/RealVNC/raspi-preview

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to install tightvnc

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/

Answer (score 0):

I use tightvncserver

```
    sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
```

Hope it helps,
Bilbo